# AutoLayout design for ios7 4S and IOS8 5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I had developed an app for my client, my client and I are using iPhone 4s(IOS7). Recently my client used my code in 5c(IOS8). Now there are various issues in that. Now I started R&D on those issues.
someone suggested me to design UI Using `AutoLayout`. In my project I am not using XIB, I am only doing it programatically, I am not in touch with XIbs. So Now I started doing R&D on AutoLayout programmatically. But I am not able to understand it (AutoLayout Programmatically). Any suggestions?

### IOS 7 4S

[image]

### IOS8  5S

[image]

Comment: in my choice u using the autoresizing, it is better for your design

Answer (score 1):

First do some reading up to understand what autolayout actually is and how it should be used. Take a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) and/or watch [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout). They both are using storyboards but they can help you to understand the concepts of autolayout. On Ray Wederlich's site, you can also find other documentation on how to use autolayout pragmatically but I think you have to pay for this. It's worth it but you can also find other help online for free.

The basics I follow are:

- Create the view

  ```
  UIView *myView = [UIView new];
  ```
- Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property

  ```
  myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  ```
- Add view as subview

  ```
  [self.view addSubview:myView];
  ```
- Add the constraints

  ```
  NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView 
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.view 
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                          multiplier:1.0 
                            constant:0.0];

  [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
  ```

You need to add multiple constraints in order to layout the view exactly as you want in relation to the other views around it.

I also suggest either creating your own category in order to make writing the autolayout code quicker and easier to understand when reading it back. Here's one for example: [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)

If you're able to make your question a bit more specific it may be possible to give you some better example code but your question is too big and broad for that so take the advise given in this answer as well as the others and do some reading up on the topic. Start by making a simple project and using autolayout to layout a few views and then as you get more confident, build up to more complex views.

Comment: @Hoston, just add the code [yourview addConstraints : constraint];

Comment: Cheers. I knew i'd miss something out as I was doing it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to use the `auto layout` in programmatically use this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm) and the another link is [here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

this contains all the `NSLayout` enum types available in **UIKIT** framework under the `NSLayoutConstraint.h` file.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSLayoutAttribute) {
NSLayoutAttributeLeft = 1,
NSLayoutAttributeRight,
NSLayoutAttributeTop,
NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
NSLayoutAttributeWidth,
NSLayoutAttributeHeight,
NSLayoutAttributeCenterX,
NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,
NSLayoutAttributeBaseline,

NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute = 0
};
```

Comment: if u need assistance ask me , surely i hope with u